# Execute an insert or update using Diesel

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I am trying to execute an insert or update using [Diesel](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel) with PostgreSQL.

I have tried:

```
diesel::insert_into($table::table).values(&objects).on_conflict($table::id).do_update().set(&objects).execute(conn).unwrap();
```

where `objects` is a `std::vec::Vec<Struct>` - which results in the compiler error:

```
^^^ the trait 'diesel::query_builder::AsChangeset' is not implemented for '&std::vec::Vec<Struct>'
```

There is a `on_conflict_do_nothing()` in the query builder but I can't seem to find something like `on_conflict_do_update()` or `on_conflict_do_replace()`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Diesel 1.3.3's documentation](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.3.3/diesel/pg/upsert/struct.IncompleteOnConflict.html) already has examples for using an upsert:

**Set specific value on conflict**

```
diesel::insert_into(users)
    .values(&user2)
    .on_conflict(id)
    .do_update()
    .set(name.eq("I DONT KNOW ANYMORE"))
    .execute(&conn);
```

**Set [`AsChangeset`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.3.3/diesel/query_builder/trait.AsChangeset.html) struct on conflict**

```
diesel::insert_into(users)
    .values(&user2)
    .on_conflict(id)
    .do_update()
    .set(&user2)
    .execute(&conn);
```

**Use [`excluded`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.3.3/diesel/pg/upsert/fn.excluded.html) to get the rejected value**

```
diesel::insert_into(users)
    .values(&vec![user2, user3])
    .on_conflict(id)
    .do_update()
    .set(name.eq(excluded(name)))
    .execute(&conn)
```

---

[`IncompleteDoUpdate::set`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.3.3/diesel/pg/upsert/struct.IncompleteDoUpdate.html#method.set) takes any value that implements [`AsChangeset`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.3.3/diesel/query_builder/trait.AsChangeset.html), which `&Vec<T>` does not. Thus it is invalid to pass it as an argument to `set`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Took me a while to realize that I could use `excluded` using the `id` - this works: `diesel::insert_into($table::table).values(&objects).on_confl‌​ict($table::id).do_u‌​pdate().set($table::‌​id.eq(excluded($tabl‌​e::id))).execute(con‌​n).unwrap`

Comment: hey, and do you know how to make this works for the sqlite?

Comment: @privalou this kind of syntax does not appear supported by Diesel for SQLIte

Answer (score 3):

In case you need to specify how to update multiple columns on conflict, the `set` function accepts a tuple.

For example:

```rust
use diesel::pg::upsert::excluded;

let user = User { id: 1, name: "Pascal", age: 18 };
let user2 = User { id: 1, name: "Sean", age: 21 };
let user3 = User { id: 2, name: "Tess", age: 25 };

assert_eq!(Ok(1), diesel::insert_into(users).values(&user).execute(&conn));

let insert_count = diesel::insert_into(users)
    .values(&vec![user2, user3])
    .on_conflict(id)
    .do_update()
    .set((
        name.eq(excluded(name)),
        age.eq(excluded(age)),
    ))
    .execute(&conn);
```

See: https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/fn.update.html#examples