# How can I upsert an array of values in Diesel?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I'm trying to upsert with the `AsChangeSet` method as described by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47626103/1350184), but instead of a single value, I'm trying to upsert an array of values. The database back-end I'm using is PostgreSQL. It's not possible for me to use a tuple because the array is retrieved from an external source.

```rust
let new_users = vec![user1, user2];

diesel::insert_into(users)
    .values(&new_users)
    .on_conflict(id)
    .do_update()
    .set(&new_users)
    .execute(&conn);
```

This throwns a compiler error about the trait `AsChangeSet` not being implemented for `&Vec<User>`, even though it is implemented for `User`.

How can I properly upsert a vector of values?

Comment: "This throwns a compiler error" — please add the complete compiler error.

Comment: @cafce25 error[E0277]: the trait bound `&Vec<User>: AsChangeset` is not satisfied

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the **complete** error message from the compiler (`cargo build`), not your IDE.

Comment: Why do you need the complete error message when it's obvious that `AsChangeset` has no implementation for `Vec<T>` or `&[T]` in Diesel? I'm trying to find a way to upsert an array of values, not to see what's wrong with my code. Basically what's described in this issue: https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/2032 but for upserting instead of just updating.

Comment: Because a future visitor might be looking for an error in their code, without the full error message in the question it's much harder to find, Q/As that can't be found are not useful, but that's the goal of Stack Overflow, provide a library of useful Q/A pairs.

Comment: Your question is answered in the link, specifically [this answer](/a/70857982/2189130) which shows how to do this with `excluded`. That is how you do upserts on an array of values.

Comment: *"It's not possible for me to use a tuple"* - if you're referring to the answer I linked, it is a tuple of *columns* to be updated, and you are beholden to Postgres's syntax; Diesel just follows it. You *need* to tell Postgres which columns to update on conflict (there is no "all" option).